# How to use transform property in css to get border line

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

Requirement image

[image: Requirement image]

My image

[image: My image]

Once look at these 2 images requirement image is what I need and My image is what I got the output I need the output like requirement image how to get that border blue line and icon as shown in the requirement image please check the below code and help me with the solution in stackblitz

```css
.psudo:after{
  content:"";
    position:absolute;
    border-width:92px;
    border-style:solid;
    border-color:#fff;
    border-right-color:transparent;
    border-left-color:transparent;
    border-bottom-color:transparent;
    z-index:99;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    transform:translateX(90px)
}
```

```html
<div class="psudo" style="width:300px; height:80px; position:relative; background-color:#5f7dff;">
      <h6 class="name">Customer</h6>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative, and for the sake of completeness, without using your starting source code, that would be more suitable for responsive needs (mobile, desktop, tablet, etc.) would be to simply create a blue polygon shaped like the one you need, and insert that polygon inside a flex container altogether with the SVG icon. That seems to me like a cleaner solution. You can use this website to create CSS polygons: https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/

```css
div {
  display:flex;
  width:400px;
  justify-content:space-between;
  height:85px;
  border:1px solid #5D7AFC; /* you can add a border to the div element like this */
}

span {
clip-path: polygon(0 0, 59% 0, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
background:#5D7AFC;
width:75%;height:100%;
color:#FFF;display:flex;align-items:center;justify-content:flex-start;

}

span > span {
margin-left:15%;
}

img {
width:75px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>
    <span>Customer</span>
  </span>
  <img src="https://laurentchevrette.digital/tmp/some-icon.png">
</div>
```

Comment: Hi border blue line is missing will you please add that in code it will be very helpful to me

Comment: Added border to `div` ; feel free to mark this answer as accepted if it helped you thanks.

Answer (score 1):

there you go...
here is the complete solution I made, just replace the span content inside class named 'icon' with your desired icon.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/web-platform-kgeqeh?file=index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Document</title>
  <style>
    html,
    body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    
    .box {
      /* width: 40%; */
      border: 1px solid #5f7dff;
      overflow: hidden;
      width: 300px;
      height: 80px;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-between;
    }
    
    .customer {
      align-items: center;
      background-color: #5f7dff;
      display: inline-flex;
      position: relative;
      padding: 0 20px;
    }
    
    .customer::after {
      content: '';
      position: absolute;
      right: -80px;
      top: 0;
      width: 0;
      height: 0;
      border-bottom: 116px solid #5f7dff;
      border-right: 80px solid transparent;
    }
    
    .icon {
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      padding-right: 20px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="customer">
      <span>Customer</span>
    </div>
    <div class="icon">
      <span>icon</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the solution one issue is there here will you fill that blue shade a little bit more as per the requirement image please

Comment: @RevanthReddySince1998 this is the exact hex color using a colorpicker: #5D79FC

Comment: if my solution helped you, please upvote it.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.container {
  display:flex; /*You can use flex positioning */
  width:330px; /*set desired total width here */
  justify-content:space-between;  
}

.container img {
  width:70px;height:70px;
  z-index:10;
  }

.pseudo {
    width:300px;
    height:80px;
    position:relative;
    background-color:#5f7dff;
}

.pseudo:after{
  content:"";
    position:absolute;
    border-width:92px;
    border-style:solid;
    border-color:#fff;
    border-right-color:transparent;
    border-left-color:transparent;
    border-bottom-color:transparent;
    z-index:9;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    transform:translateX(90px)
}
```

```html
<div class="container"> <!-- insert the 'shape' and the icon (SVG,PNG,etc.) inside that same container -->
  <div class="pseudo">
        <h6 class="name">Customer</h6>
  </div>
  <img src="https://laurentchevrette.digital/tmp/some-icon.png">
</div>
```

Comment: You will probably want to use a SVG format for that icon.

Comment: You can probably put both the answers in a single answer